# Tasker Gmail Sqlite3 get emails by label (inbox) returns nothing

Tags: android, shell, sqlite, gmail, tasker

I am running a shell script in Tasker (Android) for querying my emails, but it always returns nothing.

> sqlite3
>   /data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.MYEMAIL@gmail.com.db
>   "SELECT fromAddress || '@|@' || dateSentMs || '@|@' || Subject ||
>   '@|@' || snippet FROM messages m LEFT JOIN message_labels ml ON m._id
>   = ml.message_messageId JOIN labels l ON l._id = ml.labels_id WHERE l.name = ‘^i’ ORDER BY m._id DESC;"

The code like this works ->

> sqlite3
>   /data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.MYEMAIL@gmail.com.db
>   "SELECT fromAddress || '@|@' || dateSentMs || '@|@' || Subject ||
>   '@|@' || snippet FROM messages ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT %GMAILcount;"

How can I get this to work?

The tables are formed like this

> MESSAGE_LABELS 0|_id|INTEGER|0||1 1|labels_id|INTEGER|1||0
>   2|message_messageId|INTEGER|1||0 3|message_conversation|INTEGER|0||0
>
> LABELS 0|_id|INTEGER|0||1 1|canonicalName|TEXT|0||0 2|name|TEXT|0||0
>   3|numConversations|TEXT|0||0 4|numUnreadConversations|TEXT|0||0
>   5|color|INTEGER|0|2147483647|0 6|systemLabel|INTEGER|0|0|0
>   7|systemLabelOrder|INTEGER|0|0|0 8|hidden|INTEGER|0|0|0
>   9|labelCountDisplayBehavior|INTEGER|0|0|0
>   10|labelSyncPolicy|INTEGER|0|0|0 11|visibility|TEXT|0||0
>   12|lastTouched|INTEGER|0|0|0 13|numUnseenConversations|INTEGER|0|0|0
>   14|lastMessageTimestamp|INTEGER|1|0|0
>
> MESSAGES 0|_id|INTEGER|0||1 1|messageId|INTEGER|0||0
>   2|conversation|INTEGER|0||0 3|fromAddress|TEXT|0||0
>   4|toAddresses|TEXT|0||0 5|ccAddresses|TEXT|0||0
>   6|bccAddresses|TEXT|0||0 7|replyToAddresses|TEXT|0||0
>   8|dateSentMs|INTEGER|0||0 9|dateReceivedMs|INTEGER|0||0
>   10|subject|TEXT|0||0 11|snippet|TEXT|0||0 12|listInfo|TEXT|0||0
>   13|personalLevel|INTEGER|0||0 14|body|TEXT|0||0
>   15|bodyEmbedsExternalResources|INTEGER|0||0
>   16|joinedAttachmentInfos|STRING|0||0 17|synced|INTEGER|0||0
>   18|error|TEXT|0||0 19|clientCreated|INTEGER|0||0
>   20|refMessageId|INTEGER|0|0|0 21|forward|INTEGER|0|0|0
>   22|includeQuotedText|INTEGER|0|0|0 23|quoteStartPos|INTEGER|0|0|0
>   24|bodyCompressed|BLOB|0|NULL|0 25|customFromAddress|TEXT|0|NULL|0
>   26|queryId|INTEGER|0|1|0 27|spamDisplayedReasonType|INTEGER|0||0
>   28|deliveryChannel|INTEGER|0||0
>   29|referencesRfc822MessageIds|TEXT|0||0
>   30|showSendersFullEmailAddress|INTEGER|0||0 31|viaDomain|TEXT|0||0
>   32|showForgedFromMeWarning|INTEGER|0||0 33|refAdEventId|TEXT|0||0
>   34|permalink|TEXT|0||0 35|clipped|INTEGER|0|0|0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.YOUREMAIL@gmail.com.db "SELECT fromAddress || '@|@' || dateSentMs || '@|@' || Subject || '@|@' || snippet FROM messages m LEFT JOIN message_labels ml ON m.messageId = ml.message_messageId JOIN labels l ON l._id = ml.labels_id WHERE l.name = '^i' ORDER BY m._id;"

Is the correct one. m.messageId instead of just _id

Comment: doest it actually work? I've tried that one too, but result is still nothing

Comment: @tomaski Did you replace YOUREMAIL with your gmail address?  And did you check root in tasker? And installed sqlite3 on your rooted device?

Comment: You can also try '^all' instead of '^i'

Answer (score 0):

your query seems to be fine, so my bet is that joined tables return `NULL`

what `_id` do you get when query `SELECT * FROM labels WHERE name = '^i'`

in my case, it's `1` and when I run:

`SELECT * FROM message_labels WHERE labels_id=1`

I get.... nothing :) so here is where your code might be failing too

p.s.

I do recommend installing [SQLiteDebugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin) - it is a tremendous help when working on more complex queries